# Summing list of [row, column, value] into 2 dim list in python

Tags: python

I have a list of [row_index, column_index, value]. The row and column can be duplicated. I'd like to summing up this list to a matrix style list.

For instance,

```
list_of_list = [[0,0,1], [0,0,1], [1,0,3], [1,1,4]]
matrix_style_list = get_matrix_style_list(list_of_list)
print(matrix_style_list)

[[2, 0], [3, 4]]
```

On above example, value of `0 x 0` is `2` because `list_of_list` contains `[0,0,1], [0,0,1]` and `1 + 1 = 2`

Comment: why `[[2, 3], [0, 4]]`?

Comment: @gefei, thanks. I updated the question.

Comment: It should be `[[2, 0],[3, 4]]` right?

Comment: @AnandSKumar Oh, sorry. It's my fault...

Answer (score 2):

Build a dictionary that adds each sublist's last value to the value corresponding to a key of a tuple of the sublist's first two values:

```
>>> list_of_list = [[0,0,1], [0,0,1], [1,0,3], [1,1,4]]
>>> d = {}
>>> for item in list_of_list:
...     *location, datum = item
...     location = tuple(location)
...     d[location] = d.get(location, 0) + datum
...
>>> d
{(1, 0): 3, (0, 0): 2, (1, 1): 4}
```

Find the size of the matrix:

```
>>> rows = max(item[0] for item in list_of_list)
>>> columns = max(item[1] for item in list_of_list)
```

Then you can create a matrix structure with a comprehension:

```
>>> structure = [[d.get((row, column), 0) for column in range(columns+1)] for row in range(rows+1)]
>>> structure
[[2, 0], [3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution to this would be to first find out the shape of the output array by using `max()` function , and then create an matrix of that shape with all `0` , and then keep summing the values from your `list_of_list` to that output_matrix. Example -

```
list_of_list = [[0,0,1], [0,0,1], [1,0,3], [1,1,4]]
import operator
def get_matrix_style_list(lol):
    x_shape,y_shape = max(lol, key=operator.itemgetter(0,1))[0:2] 
    output_matrix = [[0 for _ in range(y_shape+1)] for _ in range(x_shape +1)]
    for x,y,val in lol:
        output_matrix[x][y] += val 
    return output_matrix
```

Demo -

```
>>> list_of_list = [[0,0,1], [0,0,1], [1,0,3], [1,1,4]]
>>> import operator
>>> def get_matrix_style_list(lol):
...     x_shape,y_shape = max(lol, key=operator.itemget
...     output_matrix = [[0 for _ in range(y_shape+1)]
...     for x,y,val in lol:
...         output_matrix[x][y] += val
...     return output_matrix
...
>>> get_matrix_style_list(list_of_list)
[[2, 0], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: I am just too lazy to write `list_of_list` , so I abbreviated it :)